# What is the difference between 좋다 and 좋아하다?

Tags: difference, verb, adjective

This is a [question from the proposal phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/74126#74126).

What is the difference between 좋다 and 좋아하다?

How do we distinguish between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Derivation of 좋아하다

1. 좋다 is an adjective that means *good*.
2. Appending the 하 to its infinitive form 좋아 creates a compound, where it is given a notion of *feeling*.
   Thus, 좋아하다 has a "raw" meaning of something like... *to feel good about*.
3. Apply that to some object and one would quickly find that they *like* that thing. Hence ultimately, 좋아하다 has come to adopt the meaning of *to like*.

#### Examples

- 이런 산법은 **좋다**: Such algorithm is **good**.
- 그는 사과를 **좋아하다**: He **likes** apples.
- 난 네가 **좋다**: (To) me, you are **good**.   →  I **like** you.
  This one may be a little weird, but if you follow how 좋아하다 was derived from the section above, you can quickly come to the conclusion that "To me, you are good." can adopt a meaning of "I like you".

#### Generalizing the pattern

Now I'm really only beginning to learn how to "transform" words, and I don't know what adjectives can use this and what cannot, but as far as I know things to do with feelings can use this derivation:

- 아프다 painful (eg a painful wound) → 아파하다 to feel pain / be in pain (eg to feel pain due to the wound)
- 슬프다 sad (eg a sad story) → 슬퍼하다 to feel sad(eg to feel sad listening to the story)
- 그립다 longed for, dear → 그리워하다 to miss (think "to feel something that you long/yearn for"), as in "I miss you"
- 밉다 unpleasant → 미워하다 dislike ("to feel something unpleasant")

In addition, for a sentence like the "I like you" example above, for a **transitive** verb, it can be said that if
A가 B를 C아/어하다
then it is equivalent to say
A는 B가 C다
Note, however, that the former is used if A is a third person, otherwise the latter form is used.

Comment: The derivation and examples are OK, but the generalization misses an important point because 좋아하다 is kind of an exception. -아/어하다 is usually only added to feeling verbs if other people are 'feeling' them (3rd person). For 1st person (and asking in 2nd person) the -아/어하다 is usually not added. I think the explanation is that only the person feeling can truly know what they are feeling. Other people can only observe what they perceive that person to be feeling (thus -아/어하다 is added).

Comment: @Leftium can you show me some examples? And perhaps some sources? I would like to look into this.

Comment: I don't have my Korean textbooks handy at the moment, but here is a good example with discussion: [-고 싶다](https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/3c85if/%EC%8B%B6%EC%96%B4%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4_vs_%EC%8B%B6%EB%8B%A4/)

Comment: OK, here is a source: [Intermediate College Korean, pp 77-78](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=SFvw2h0Q8dYC&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&#v=snippet&q=%22d.v%20%2B%20(%EC%96%B4%2F%EC%95%84)%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4%22). The rule is not explicitly stated but the examples clearly alternate between 1st person and 3rd person with the same verb using the two different forms. (Also notice both 좋다/좋아하다 are used for 1st person)

Comment: @Leftium thank you very much :-) I have updated the answer accordingly. I wonder though, is this a strong tendency or a rule? For example 2ne1's song "Missing You" actually has a line *그리워해요* saying *I miss you*. Is this so because it's just a tendency or is the lyric incorrect/unnatural?

Answer (score 3):

좋다 -> adjective, A(이/가) 좋다 describes that A is good

예)
날씨가 좋다 -> the weather is good
성격이 좋다 -> (have) a good character

좋아하다 -> verb, describes the act of liking something/one
예)
너를 좋아하다 ->(I) like you
떡을 좋아하다 -> (I) like rice cake

Answer (score 2):

Basically, '좋다' is a predicate. It **can be used as an adjective, an adverb, and a verb.**
As others told, basically 좋다 is an adjective in many cases. However, if you try to use it to describe a behavior, then it is verb. For example,

나는 네가 **좋다**. (I like you.)

It can also be felt like an adverb when you translate the sentence in English.

나는 기분이 **좋다** (I feel good.)

And of course, like this, it can be used as an adjective.
이 제품은 **좋다**. (This product is good.)

What you have to know is, Korean grammar usually classifies words with their role, not with their form or notation.

In contrast, **좋아하다** is obviously a verb. It **can only be used as a verb**.  This is because of its ending, -하다.